# JSON sub for loop produces KeyError, but key exists

Tags: python, json, list, for-loop, dictionary

I'm trying to add the JSON output below into a dictionary, to be saved into a SQL database.

```
{'Parkirisca': [
    {    
    'ID_Parkirisca': 2,
    'zasedenost': {
                   'Cas': '2016-10-08 13:17:00',
                   'Cas_timestamp': 1475925420,
                   'ID_ParkiriscaNC': 9,
                   'P_kratkotrajniki': 350
                  }
    }
]}
```

I am currently using the following code to add the value to a dictionary:

```
import scraperwiki
import json
import requests
import datetime
import time
from pprint import pprint

html = requests.get("http://opendata.si/promet/parkirisca/lpt/")

data = json.loads(html.text)

for carpark in data['Parkirisca']:

    zas = carpark['zasedenost']
    free_spaces = zas.get('P_kratkotrajniki')
    last_updated = zas.get('Cas_timestamp')

    parking_type = carpark.get('ID_Parkirisca')
    if parking_type == "Avtomatizirano":
        is_automatic = "Yes"
    else:
        is_automatic = "No"

    scraped = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    savetodb = {
    'scraped': scraped,
    'id': carpark.get("ID_Parkirisca"),
    'total_spaces': carpark.get("St_mest"),
    'free_spaces': free_spaces,
    'last_updated': last_updated,
    'is_automatic': is_automatic,
    'lon': carpark.get("KoordinataX_wgs"), 
    'lat': carpark.get("KoordinataY_wgs")
    }

    unique_keys = ['id']

    pprint savetodb
```

However when I run this, it gets stuck at `for zas in carpark["zasedenost"]` and outputs the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./code/scraper", line 17, in <module>
    for zas in carpark["zasedenost"]:
KeyError: 'zasedenost'
```

I've been led to believe that `zas` is in fact now a string, rather than a dictionary, but I'm new to Python and JSON, so don't know what to search for to get a solution. I've also searched here on Stack Overflow for `KeyErrror when key exist` questions, but they didn't help, and I believe that this might be due to the fact that's a sub for loop.

Update: Now, when I swapped the double quotes for single quotes, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./code/scraper", line 17, in <module>
    free_spaces = zas.get('P_kratkotrajniki')
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Put a `print(carpark)` above the `for` loop so you can see what's in that variable.

Comment: As an aside, the "JSON" you shared is not valid JSON. (It uses single quotes.)

Comment: `print(repr(carpark))` might be even better. That will help you spot if it is indeed a `dict` as expected.

Comment: I also don't think you mean to iterate over `carpark["zasedenost"]` (since it's a dictionary). You probably just want `zas = carpark["zasedenost"]`.

Comment: In general, it would help if you shared actual runnable code that reproduces the issue. If I use `data = {'Parkirisca': ... }` and then run the rest of your code, I do *not* get a `KeyError` on the line you indicated.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just swapped out all of the double quotes for single quotes, and now I get a completely different error: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'` on this line: `free_spaces = zas.get('P_kratkotrajniki')`. I'll add the full script with the URL in my question now

Comment: That error is due to the issue I pointed out a couple comments above. You want `zas = carpark["zasedenost"]` rather than `for zas in carpark["zasedenost"]`.

Comment: But that then gives me the same key error as originally reported!

Comment: Did you add the print statement as I suggested? That would show you that the dictionary with the 'id' 6 doesn't contain 'zasedenost'. So when you get to that element in the array, you see the `KeyError` telling you that key doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh, but you'll need to use `zas = carpark["zasedenost"]` as I said. And you'll have to fix `pprint savetodb` to be something with valid Python syntax. (Maybe `pprint(savetodb)` after an `import pprint from pprint`?) Otherwise the code won't run far enough to get to the array element that's missing that key.

Comment: My mistake, I pasted an older version (pre-your suggestion). Have updated the code. Also included my imports. I'm using Python 2.x, so no parenthesis necessary on the `pprint` as far as I'm aware?
So that code above should produce a KeyError if you run it (it's exactly the same as mine now!)

Comment: See my answer. I still don't know how you're managing to get `pprint savetodb` to work... that certainly doesn't work in Python 2.7.x. Maybe you're using something even earlier?

Comment: For future questions you might ask, please include actual runnable code. E.g., in your question, the very first line uses `requests` which hasn't been defined (or imported). You're forcing people who try to help you to first use trial-and-error to figure out the right imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed up your code:

1. Added required imports.
2. Fixed the `pprint savetodb` line which isn't valid Python.
3. Didn't try to iterate over `carpark['zasedenost']`.

I then added another `pprint` statement in the `for` loop to see what's in `carpark` when the `KeyError` occurs. From there, the error is clear. (Not all the elements in the array in your JSON contain the `'zasedenost'` key.)

Here's the code I used:

```
import datetime
import json
from pprint import pprint
import time

import requests

html = requests.get("http://opendata.si/promet/parkirisca/lpt/")

data = json.loads(html.text)

for carpark in data['Parkirisca']:
    pprint(carpark)
    zas = carpark['zasedenost']
    free_spaces = zas.get('P_kratkotrajniki')
    last_updated = zas.get('Cas_timestamp')

    parking_type = carpark.get('ID_Parkirisca')
    if parking_type == "Avtomatizirano":
        is_automatic = "Yes"
    else:
        is_automatic = "No"

    scraped = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    savetodb = {
        'scraped': scraped,
        'id': carpark.get("ID_Parkirisca"),
        'total_spaces': carpark.get("St_mest"),
        'free_spaces': free_spaces,
        'last_updated': last_updated,
        'is_automatic': is_automatic,
        'lon': carpark.get("KoordinataX_wgs"), 
        'lat': carpark.get("KoordinataY_wgs")
    }

    unique_keys = ['id']

    pprint(savetodb)
```

And here's the output on the iteration where the `KeyError` occurs:

```
{u'A_St_Mest': None,
 u'Cena_dan_Eur': None,
 u'Cena_mesecna_Eur': None,
 u'Cena_splosno': None,
 u'Cena_ura_Eur': None,
 u'ID_Parkirisca': 7,
 u'ID_ParkiriscaNC': 72,
 u'Ime': u'P+R Studenec',
 u'Invalidi_St_mest': 9,
 u'KoordinataX': 466947,
 u'KoordinataX_wgs': 14.567929171694901,
 u'KoordinataY': 101247,
 u'KoordinataY_wgs': 46.05457609543313,
 u'Opis': u'2,40 \u20ac /dan',
 u'St_mest': 187,
 u'Tip_parkirisca': None,
 u'U_delovnik': u'24 ur (ponedeljek - petek)',
 u'U_sobota': None,
 u'U_splosno': None,
 u'Upravljalec': u'JP LPT d.o.o.'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    zas = carpark['zasedenost']
KeyError: 'zasedenost'
```

As you can see, the error is quite accurate. There's no key `'zasedenost'` in the dictionary. If you look through your JSON, you'll see that's true for a number of the elements in that array.

I'd suggest a fix, but I don't know what you want to do in the case where this dictionary key is absent. Perhaps you want something like this:

```
zas = carpark.get('zasedenost')
if zas is not None:
    free_spaces = zas.get('P_kratkotrajniki')
    last_updated = zas.get('Cas_timestamp')
else:
    free_spaces = None
    last_updated = None
```